# Create a new column with the sum of the values from some columns in a tibble on R

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, tibble, rowsum

I have a tibble like `Table1`, and I want to group some columns by the sum of their values for every row, creating a new column with the results and replacing the summed columns, like `Table2`.

```
Table1
| Col_A | INTER   | Col_B | Col_C | Col_D |
| ----- | ------- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
|   1   | [5-15)  |   2   |   4   |   2   |
|   1   | [15-25) |   1   |   3   |   6   |
|   1   | [25-35) |   1   |   1   |   2   |
```

In this example I'd sum values from `Col_B` and `Col_D`, saving the results in `Col_E`.

```
Table2  
| Col_A | INTER | Col_C | Col_E |
| ---   | ---   | ---   | ---   |
|   1   |   [5-15)   |   4   |  4    |
|   1   |   [15-25)   |   3   |  7    |
|   1   |   [25-35)   |   1   |  3    |
```

In my real data I have several columns (numeric variables) and they have NAs.

I tried:

```
Table2 <- Table1 %>% mutate(Col_E = rowSums(across(c(Col_B, Col_D))))
```

I got this error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Col_E`.
> i `Col_E = rowSums(...)`.
> x Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
> x Subscript has the wrong type `logical`.
> i It must be numeric or character.
> i The error occurred in group 1: Col_A = 1, INTER = "[5,15)".

Comment: I think you want `Table1 |> mutate(Col_E = Col_B + Col_D) |> select(-Col_B, -Col_D)`?

Comment: If you have many columns to sum then can use `rowSums` with `across()`, e.g, `Table1 |> mutate(Col_E = rowSums(across(c(Col_B, Col_D))))`, and `across()` has the advantage of letting you use select helpers in case there's a more programmatic way you want to pick the columns to sum.

Comment: Thank you so much, I used `mutate(Col_E = rowSums(across(c(Col_B, Col_D)), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% select(Col_A, INTER, Col_C, Col_E)`. Is there a easier/simpler way to select/delete the columns that I want without writting them one by one (either select the remainings plus Col_E or deleting the summed columns)? because in my data there are numerous columns and with kinda long names

Comment: @DaniQuinchero a couple of things: 1. there's a lot of ways of selecting columns, check the documentation: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html . I don't know if I understand what you mean by "select the remainings plus Col_E" but maybe play around with `everything()` or the other ones in the documentation, and tell me how you go

Comment: 2. If you have your answer, post it as an answer! It's good practice and helps future readers :-)

Comment: As I and others have said, there are **many** ways to select columns. You can select them based on column number, or patterns in the names, or characteristics of the columns themselves. See the `?tidyr_tidy_select` help page for explanation and examples. We can't help you more than that unless you tell us how you want to identify the columns in your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Combining some of the input from comments before, adding a reprex with slightly modified data to address NA removal as well as examples for tidy column selection and how to pre-specify the name of the new column (useful, if you have a couple of column groups you want to aggregate and e.g. keep everything in a list to iterate over).

Here, I remove the columns that where aggregated in the last step using select(- ...), but you may also want to look into transmute(), if you are interested in keeping only the new column, but from what I read, this is not the case here.

```r
require(dplyr)
#> Loading required package: dplyr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- tribble(
~Col_A,  ~INTER,   ~ Col_B,~ Col_C,  ~Col_D ,
1     , '[5-15)'  , 2     , 4     , 2     ,
1     , '[15-25)' , 1     , 3     , NA     ,
1     , '[25-35)' , 1     , 1     , 2     
)


# pre-defined vector of column names
cols_add <- c('Col_B', 'Col_C',  'Col_D')
df %>% 
  mutate(!! col_sum := rowSums(across(all_of(cols_add)), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(-all_of(cols_add))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Col_A INTER   Col_E
#>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1     1 [5-15)      8
#> 2     1 [15-25)     4
#> 3     1 [25-35)     4

# you may also predefine the name of the result column, use !! and := in mutate 
col_sum  <- 'Col_E'

# using tidyselect with column index
df %>% 
  mutate(!! col_sum := rowSums(across(3:5), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(-all_of(cols_add))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Col_A INTER   Col_E
#>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1     1 [5-15)      8
#> 2     1 [15-25)     4
#> 3     1 [25-35)     4

# using tidyselect with regular expression
df %>% 
  mutate(!! col_sum := rowSums(across(matches('Col_[BCD]')), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(-all_of(cols_add))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Col_A INTER   Col_E
#>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1     1 [5-15)      8
#> 2     1 [15-25)     4
#> 3     1 [25-35)     4

# for multiple groups of columns to sum up
sum_spec <- list(
  col_E = c('Col_A', 'Col_B'),
  col_F = c('Col_C', 'Col_D')
)
 
df2 <- df 
iwalk(sum_spec, ~{
  df2 <<- df2 %>% 
    mutate( !! .y := rowSums(across(all_of(.x)), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    select(-all_of(.x))
})

df2
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   INTER   col_E col_F
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 [5-15)      3     6
#> 2 [15-25)     2     3
#> 3 [25-35)     2     3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the suggestion of creating a list of variables I want to sum, but then I just used the simple `select()` function, because I wanted to order my columns in a specific way (different from the Table1, not illustrated in the example data).

```
cols_add <- (Col_B, Col_D)

Table2 <- Table1 %>%
 mutate(Col_E = rowSums(across(all_of(cols_add)), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
 select(Col_A, INTER, Col_C, Col_E)
```

But in the case I want the default order of the columns from Table1, I'd have used this:

```
cols_add <- (Col_B, Col_D)

Table2 <- Table1 %>%
 mutate(Col_E = rowSums(across(all_of(cols_add)), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
 select(!cols_add)
```

Thank you all for your help